# Why does `map2_chr` sometimes return a `character(0)`?

Tags: r, purrr

I need to be able to use the keys in a list. With `purrr`, I use the `map2` family (here `map2_chr`) and use `names(.)` to get the keys.
However, when the original list is only 1 element long, and has no key, `map2_chr` sends back an empty vector.

I've opened an issue on the `purrr` repo, as I think this might be a bug.

```r
library(purrr)
alist <- list("bla") 
alist %>% 
  map_chr(~ .)
#> [1] "bla"
alist %>% 
  map2_chr(.y = NULL, ~ .x)
#> character(0)
alist %>% 
  map2_chr(.y = alist, ~ .x)
#> [1] "bla"
```

I'm looking for a way to get `"bla"` event when the value of `.y` is `NULL`.

Comment: Not relevant but please don't use names like `alist`. I also think it's to do with mapping `NULL` to x which returns NULL

Comment: @NelsonGon "names like `alist`" seems pretty meaningless to me, you could explain that better, cheers.

Comment: `alist` might mask the function `alist` although it might be less important if one is not going to end up debugging I guess @jay.sf I would go with `a_list` just to be safe and perhaps remain in `tidyverse` convention.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if that would be possible with `NULL` since

```
length(NULL)
#[1] 0
```

From `?map2`

> If all input is length 0, the output will be length 0. If any input is length 1, it will be recycled to the length of the longest.

Hence, you get `character(0)`.

If one input is length 1 then it is recycled

```
alist %>% map2_chr(.y = 1:5, ~ .x)
#[1] "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla"
```

Comment: I found some interesting source code, probably the shortest I've seen in the `tidyverse` for `is_empty` which might have been written to handle such issues.

Comment: @NelsonGon haaa..True.., it is really short. I doubt if we really need a function for that..

Comment: Hahah..Gave me a chuckle when I saw it.